# Advertisement link click counts not matching up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, links, advertising, click-tracking

We are using tracking software that reports how many clicks advertisement links on our website get.  This is not matching with the stat given by Google Analytics.

Does Google Analytics track sessions instead of clicks to links? What is the difference between sessions and clicks on Google analytics?

Comment: Google Analytics doesn't usually track the number of clicks on external links (including advertising) at all.

Answer (score 1):

I find tracking software to be slightly misleading.  A "click" will indicate how many times a visitor has clicked an ad.  A visitor may click the same ad more than once in a "session".  A session being a unique set of activities by a single visitor.  A person may leave the site and come back later and begin a new "session". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics tracks sessions and clicks.

**Clicks:** How many time someone has clicked on an ad. Google won't charge you for multiple clicks if determines they aren't valid (e.g. a user double clicking on the ad while waiting for the page to load). These clicks might not show up in your analytics, whereas they may be showing up in your other tracking software.

**Sessions:** Google Analytics estimates traffic, and therefore is not exact. If you are using AdWords, you will get exact sessions coming from AdWords, whereas if you aren't you will get an estimate.